# delay with settimeout and for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, click, delay, element

I have this code from here: 
[How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop)
I use it in console in IE, and after this code I call the function with myFunction() in console to run; This first code runs perfectly, it clicks on the second "something" tagnamed element 10 times and between the clicks are 3000 ms delay.

```
function myFunction() {
    (function myLoop (i) {          
    setTimeout(function () {   
    document.getElementsByTagName("something")[1].click();                
    if (--i) myLoop(i);      //  decrement i and call myLoop again if i > 0
   }, 3000)
})(10);
}
```

I would like to change the number "1" in this code with foor loop, so I want create a code which clicks on elements named "something".
I created this code, but is not working:

```
for (x=1;x<10;x++){
function myFunction() {
(function myLoop (i) {          
    setTimeout(function () {   
    document.getElementsByTagName("something")[1].click();                
    if (--i) myLoop(i);      //  decrement i and call myLoop again if i > 0
   }, 3000)
})(10);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print each element at an interval you need to multiply the timing value with an integer, otherwise all of them will be logged at one time.

Also you may not need to create `myFunction` inside the loop

```js
for (var x = 1; x < 5; x++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(i);
    }, i * 1000)
  }(x))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It usually easier to use `setInterval` rather the a loop with `setTimeout`. Everything is just simpler:

```js
var count = 10
var intv = setInterval(function(){
  if (count === 0 ) {
    clearInterval(intv)
    console.log("done")
    return
   }
  // do something
  console.log(count--)
}, 1000)
```

But you can recursively call `setTimeout`:

```js
(function myLoop (i) {          
    setTimeout(function () {   
      console.log("loop: ", i)
      if (--i) myLoop(i);      
   }, 1000)
})(10);
```

Putting the whole thing in a for loop AND calling it recursively is strange though, because the loop will run and make a bunch of individual timeouts that will all run independently, which I don't think is what you want.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function myFunction() {
    (function myLoop (i) {          
        setTimeout(function () {   
        document.getElementsByTagName("div")[1].click();                
        if (--i) myLoop(i);      //  decrement i and call myLoop again if i > 0
        }, 3000)
    })(10);
  }

for (x=1;x<10;x++){
  myFunction();
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
```

Try like this. I used `div` instead of `something`

Comment: This code also clicks on the second div element, I want loop through the div elements->  (div)[x]

Comment: I tried your code with some changes: i pass the argument x in the foor loop to the myFunction, so the function definition will be function myFunction(x){}  and inside the for loop is myFunction(x);  but this also doesnt work, because now clicks on the last element in the foor loop only, for example if i define the for loop as for(x=1;x<5;x++) then only the 4. elemnt will be clicked.

Comment: brk has right, it is needed to multiply the timing value with an integer.