# delay with settimeout and for loop + 1 more delay

Tags: javascript, nested, click, settimeout, delay

In my previous asked question, I had some problem with delaying. Previous question:
[delay with settimeout and for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53407769/delay-with-settimeout-and-for-loop/53407869?noredirect=1#comment93690842_53407869)

My purpose is get some datas from a website, and I use console in IE.
The content is changed when the user clicks on an element which has tagname "something"

This code runs perfectly if i want only to clicking on the elements through:

```
for (var x = 1; x < 5; x++) {
    (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("something")[i].click();    }, i * 1000)
  }(x))
}
```

But in my casy i need also get the content from the site after clicking, so I added a new line after clicking:

```
myarray=[];
        for (var x = 1; x < 5; x++) {
            (function(i) {
                setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementsByTagName("something")[i].click();
    var x=theelement.innerHTML;
    myarray.push(x);
    }, i * 1000)
          }(x))
        }
```

So with an array I can get the contents after clicking. The problem is that after the clicking the site loads ~1-2 seconds and my above code **tries immediately** get the element and assign its innerHTML value to the x variable.

I tried to making a "nested delay" inside the delay but not works, because they evaluate separetly. So I tried to solve like this the problem:

```
outer settime with delay 1000ms
   element.click()
      inner settime with delay 3000ms
          x=element.innerhtml
      innersettime close tag
outer settime close tag
```

In this case the inner settime and the outer settime evaluates separatly and not like a well-known sleep() functions like in other languages. The purpose is making delay between "clicking" and "get the content of an element" functions. And this 2 functions must be repeated 30 times. And between these 30 times also must be delay.

```
link1.click();
3sec pause;   -->this is the pause between "click" and "get content"
x=elem1.innerHTML;
myarray.push(x);
1sec pause;
link2.click();
3secpause;  --> this is the pause between each loop (there is 30link on the site)
x=elem2.innerHTML;
myarray.push(x);
until link30.click()....
```

The url doesnt change, only the content.

Comment: can you please create a demo of what exactly you need

Comment: I specified it at the end.